# Single word for thing which will never repeat in life

Tags: single-word-requests

Consider:

> Childhood never comes again in life.

What might be single word that means *never come again in life*?

Comment: What part of speech are you looking for? Noun? Adjective?

Comment: In my opinion, it was not a duplicate even it leads to the same answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is ***one-off*** in BrE.

> **1.** *adj.* Happening, done, or made only once. 
>   **2.** *n.* Something that is not repeated or reproduced.
>
> <sub><sup>Source:http://www.thefreedictionary.com/one-off</sup></sub>

Example: (from the book "Global Citizenship and the Legacy of Empire: Marketing Development" By April Biccum)

> **Childhood is a one-off window of development**, which makes investing in children a priority but not a choice. Damage at this stage **cannot be overcome later in life**. Northern child poverty is the root of the most serious social problem facing these countries in the future.
>
> (Wilkinson, 2000, p. 17, my emphasis)

Comment: one-off is the best match.

Answer (score 7):

> Quoth the Raven “Nevermore.” - E. A. Poe

The word you are looking for is [nevermore](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nevermore):

> never again; never thereafter: *And nevermore were the elves seen in that town.*

Answer (score 4):

The expression  [once-in-a-lifetime](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/once-in-a-lifetime) may fit:

> - Describes an experience or opportunity that is very special because you will probably only have it once : A tour of Australia is a once-in-a-lifetime experience .
> - A chance that will never occur again in one's lifetime. This is a once-in-a-lifetime chance. Don't miss it. She offered me a once-in-a-lifetime opportunity, but I turned it down.